# How do I stop Android Studio from highlighting specific words when double clicking?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Whenever I double click on whatever contains more than one word in it, Android Studio will highlight the word it thinks I'm clicking on rather than that entire value.

Take `View.findViewById` for instance. Double clicking on `findViewById` will either highlight `find`, `View`, `By`, or `Id`, but I just want it to select `findViewById`. I've gone through Android Studio's preferences, but I didn't see anything that looked like a toggle or option for this.

More examples:

```
private String fooBar;
```

This will either highlight `foo` or `Bar` depending on where I click.

```
myView.addView(...);
```

This will either highlight `my`/`View` or `add`/`View`, but not `myView` or `addView`.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio open Settings/Editor/General/Smart Keys end disable checkbox <Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click>

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidStudio or Intellij Idea

1. navigate to `Settings`.
2. Click on `Editor` on the left menu.
3. Then click on `General'.
4. Uncheck the option labelled `Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click`